# CSS изменение изображения при наведении

Tags: css

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Эффект перекатывания</title>
  <style type="text/css">
   A.rollover {
    background: url(images/sun1.png); /* Путь к файлу с исходным рисунком  */
    display: block; /* Рисунок как блочный элемент */
    width: 196px; /* Ширина рисунка */
    height: 183px; /* Высота рисунка */
   }
   A.rollover:hover {
    background: url(images/sun2.png); /* Путь к файлу с заменяемым рисунком  */
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p><a href="#" class="rollover"> </a></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

На сайте будет расположено 8 изображений.
Как сделать 8 таких элементов ? 
Т.е. *две строки по 4 столбца*.
Каждое изображение имеет ссылку.
CSS знаю плохо.

В итоге должно получиться нечто вроде: [Скрин](http://i4.imageban.ru/out/2012/01/10/929f745a48a1379f4fc11e8449c4a26b.png)

Answer (score 1):

Можно по старинке, сверстать таблицами. Я сгруппировал все стили картинок для краткости. Но вы можете прописать для каждой свой отдельный бэкграунд.
Если не нравятся таблицы, можно сделать то же самое с помощью `div` и `float` или `display: table-cell`.

```css
table { width: 100%; }
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}
.img1, .img2, .img3, 
.img4, .img5, .img6 { 
   background: lightyellow; 
}
.img1:hover, .img2:hover, .img3:hover, 
.img4:hover, .img5:hover, .img6:hover { 
  background: red; 
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="img1">1</td>
    <td class="img2">2</td>
    <td class="img3">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="img4">4</td>
    <td class="img5">5</td>
    <td class="img6">6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так:

```
A.rollover {
    background: url(images/sun1.png); /* Путь к файлу с исходным рисунком  */
    display: inline-block; /* Рисунок как блочный элемент */
    width: 196px; /* Ширина рисунка */
    height: 183px; /* Высота рисунка */
   }
p {width: 784px;}
```

Как вариант:

```
A.rollover {
        background: url(images/sun1.png); /* Путь к файлу с исходным рисунком  */
        display: block; /* Рисунок как блочный элемент */
        float: left;
        width: 196px; /* Ширина рисунка */
        height: 183px; /* Высота рисунка */
       }
```

Comment: Как тогда быть с ссылками ?(забыл про них сразу упомянуть)

Comment: А что с ними? Мы же только стиль меняем, логика остается прежней.

Comment: Я хочу получить такое вот дело: http://i4.imageban.ru/out/2012/01/10/929f745a48a1379f4fc11e8449c4a26b.png
Каждое изображение будет ссылкой и при наведении будет приобретать цвет. Я не могу расположить несколько таких изображений в таком виде. Одно получается, больше не могу.

Comment: Смотрите внимательно мой ответ, там описано два способа: 

display: inline-block; 

или 

display: block;
float: left;